# Use google spreadsheet as database

Tags: php, wordpress, excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My task is to get information from an excel spreadsheet on google with php and display data from it on a website.
I will need to do this on a site that already has wordpress on it, and I am not very good with wordpress.

Any idea? I found google spreadsheet API, but I don't find anything php-related other than stuff related to Zend Framework. As I have no experience with that, I would highly appreciate if you could give me a solution using just core php.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780804/how-do-i-read-a-google-drive-spreadsheet-in-php maybe the second last answer is helpful. PHP has CSV parsing functions built in.

Comment: Agree with Joni, if you only need to read, that is the best solution I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

extract data from google spreadsheet as json and use javascript in wordpress post or page to display content