# PHP: Downloading/reading Google Drive Sheet

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have been using the following code (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18106727/9829696), seems to be popular around the internet) to download and use a CSV-file from a Google Drive Sheet:

```
$spreadsheet_url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=<somecode>&single=true&gid=0&output=csv";

if(!ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 15)) echo "<!-- unable to change socket timeout -->";

if (($handle = fopen($spreadsheet_url, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $spreadsheet_data[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
else
    die("Problem reading csv");
```

However, this script stopped working for me a few weeks ago. The link downloads the CSV-file just fine if done manually, but no longer happens using the script.

Has anyone had this problem and found a solution? Otherwise, what other option works? I cannot get the "[official way](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php)" to work (it's just stuck in "Enabling API..." forever), and I hear many others can't get this to work either.

Comment: What is the output when you run this code? Are you getting an error back from google? Can you use curl/wget to get the file?

Comment: The output is simply "Problem reading csv". No errors according to the console. curl scripts seem to fair no better with the link. wget I'm afraid I am unfamiliar with in php.

Comment: If you can't access the file directly from command line using curl or wget (unix program to retrieve web content), that would appear to be a network error.